# Is there any built-in factorial function in c++?

Tags: c++

I have searched but I was not able to find this. Would anyone please tell me that if there is any built-in factorial function in c++ ?

Comment: `return (n == 1 || n == 0) ? 1 : factorial(n - 1) * n`

Comment: You can implement your own function. It should be trivial.

Comment: You kinda end up needing some sort of big int type if you care about the exact values of the factorial for non-trivial case. C++ doesn't have a big int type, so I imagine that's why no standard factorial function exists.

Comment: @Sumeet for the same reason you wouldn't write your own std::vector.

Comment: There [is one in Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/factorials/sf_factorial.html).

Answer (score 51):

Although there is no C function defined specifically for computing factorials, C math library lets you compute [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). Since Г(n) = (n-1)! for positive integers, using [`tgamma`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/tgamma) of `i+1` yields `i!`.

If you use a user-defined factorial function, this would print identical numbers:

```
for (int i = 1 ; i != 10 ; i++) {
    printf("%lld %f\n", factorial(i), tgamma(i+1));
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/J6YtfK)

```
1 1.000000
2 2.000000
6 6.000000
24 24.000000
120 120.000000
720 720.000000
5040 5040.000000
40320 40320.000000
362880 362880.000000
```

**Note:** Considering how easy it is to code up factorial function, using gamma to compute factorials is a lot like killing a fly with a sledgehammer.

Comment: Ninja'd me by a few seconds. But it's probably a bad idea to use this function. It's an overkill similar to `std::pow(x,2)`.

Comment: Huh, so they actually hacked together function overloading with macros for this? 0.o Talking about the `tgamma` from <tgmath.h>.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Yes, this is some serious hacking! It looks like `tgmath.h` does it for all functions in `math.h`.

Comment: The up side of using this function is that there may be optimisations if you're doing a lot of them.

Comment: @UKMonkey How many could you possibly do before you overflow your `long long`? You can do all of them, I mean, all twenty of them, upfront, store the results in a look-up table, and have your factorial whenever you want it. Precomputation takes a total of 20 multiplications :-) :-) :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You are off by one, the first 21 fit. (0! to 20!) ;P

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that there is also the [`lgamma`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/lgamma) function that returns the natural logarithm of the gamma function. This addresses the numerical issue that the values of the gamma function very easily don't fit into a `long` and not even into a `double`.

Comment: I don't think tgamma is too much, it's just i+1 to do

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no such function in the Standard Library.

Answer (score 6):

No, in standard c++ , there is no such function as factorial ,But you can find same functionality in boost library : [`boost::math::factorial`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/factorials/sf_factorial.html)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned previously, there is no such a function in the standard library. Since recursive definitions may be not optimal in the terms of execution speed, I would recommend the iterative aproach:

```
long factorial(const int n)
{
    long f = 1;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; ++i)
        f *= i;
    return f;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Writing a slow version of factorial even with DP in C or C++ is easy. However, there is a much faster algorithm implemented in Python 3:

See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ffcc7cd57f6a52c6074ecc9f0a9f0177fb1dbfee/Modules/mathmodule.c#L1905

So, it would be good to add it to the STL imho.

Answer (score 1):

STL doesn't provide function for Factorial but you can calculate in one line recursively:

```
int fact(int n){

     return (n==0) || (n==1) ? 1 : n* fact(n-1);
}
```

Comment: I would say that recursion is well suited to problems that are otherwise more complicated with iteration. A factorial function just needs a simple for loop, and you're less dependent on the compiler optimising out unnecessary function calls.

Comment: Now what happens when you need the factorial of n=100?